# z3 const declaration

Tags: python, z3

In Z3 Python,  what's the diff between  1)  `x = Const("x",IntSort())`   vs  2) `x = Int("x")`  ? is_const returns true for both and they are both ArithRef.  I would thought 1) would be appropriate for defining a const, e.g., x is 3.14   and 2) is to making a variable.

Is there a correct way to create a const variable like x = 3.14 (other than generating a formula x == 3.14)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference between `Const("x", IntSort())` and `Int("x")`. We should view `Int("x")` as syntax sugar for the former. The function `Const` is usually used to define constants of user defined sorts. Example:

```
S, (a, b, c) = EnumSort('S', ('a', 'b', 'c'))
x = Const("x", S)
```

In Z3, we use the term "variable" for universal and existential variables. Quantifier free formulas do not contain variables, only constants. In the formula, `x + 1 > 0`, we say `x` and `1` are constants. We say `x` is a uninterpreted constant, and `1` is interpreted one. That is, the meaning of `1` is fixed, but Z3 is free to assign an interpretation for `x` in order to make a formula satisfiable. If you just want to create the interpreted constant `3.14`, you can use `RealVal('3.14')`. In the following example, `x` is not a Z3 expression, but a Python variable that points to the Z3 expression `3.14`. We can use `x` as shorthand for `3.14` when building Z3 expressions/formulas. The Python variable `z` is  pointing to the Z3 expression `y`. Finally, `z > x` returns the Z3 expression `y > 3.14`. Z3Py beginners usually confuse Python variables with Z3 expressions. After the difference is clear, everything starts to make sense.

```
x = RealVal('3.14')
z = Real('y')
print z > x
```

Comment: Thanks,  that makes sense ..  Another one: does z3 or smtlib in general allow declaring variables with certain ranges ?  e.g.,  `x = [0,100]` ,i.e. `x` can only have values from 0 to 100.  I know I can declare `x` as an int and assert `0<=x <= 100` to force `x` to be within the range.

Comment: No, we have to declare `x` as an integer (or Real), and assert that `0 <= x` and `x <= 100`.

Comment: @LeonardodeMoura Could you give an example where z3 variable is used (e.g., z3.RealVar() in the python API). All the examples here (https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/advanced-examples.htm) use constants for quantified terms. I don't fully understand when would you use variables vs constants (0-arity applications) for formulas with quantifiers.